# Can an inductor be substituted for a coil

Tags: inductor, coil, receiver, frequency-modulation

I am designing this FM receiver circuit.

[image: FM Receiver using LM386]

I have a few questions related to the circuit.

1. Buying coil in my locality is a  little expensive. So would it be alright to substitute an inductor in its place? If yes, would it be alright to use a 0.2 micro-henry inductor? And also what should be the capacitance range of the variable capacitor if this is done?
2. Would it make a vast difference if I use a different transistor? I prefer using 2N3904 because it is more cheaper.
3. Can the LM386 be replaced by an ordinary class A transistor audio amplifier? Would it affect the audio signal?

Comment: A coil is an inductor - or do I mean that the other way round? Typical coils for radio receivers are easily made at home by winding a few turns of wire onto an air frame or ferite former. Google for some examples. The one in this circuit is only 4 turns!

Comment: Read what the smallprint says "This is a theoretical circuit and it requires some changes to implement it practically.". In other words it probably won't work and it will never work very well even with some modifications. TBH I can't figue out how it's meant to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Coil is easy to make - you only need 4 turns of wire! [image]
2. possibly not, 2N3904 is up to 100MHz, BF494 up to 120MHz
3. yes, you can use another amplifier. It will affect the audio according to the specifications of the amplifier, eg total harmonic distortion (THD), bandwidth, power etc.

Comment: What does THD mean?

Comment: Total harmonic distortion - how 'Hi-Fi' your class A amplifier is compared to the LM386 - edited the answer

Comment: Can I use an inductor instead of the coil? Because I can buy coil only in bulk.

Comment: The inductance of the tuner coil is likely to be much less than 0.2 micro-henry. What do you mean you can only by 'coil in bulk'? You must have some wire? otherwise how are you going to join the components together? At worst you could take the inductor apart to get the wire *it* is made from, and then wind your own coil from this.

Comment: Buy in bulk means that I can buy only an entire reel of it. They wont provide as much as I want. Anyhow, the wire I use are very thin and have many strands. Would that be alright?

Comment: Yes, you can make RF tuner coils out of thin multi strand wire.

Comment: Whereever you live, it _must_ be possible to buy a small reel of enamel wire, surely!